# Is it possible to use TFS and Github toghether?

Tags: git, github, xamarin, tfs, xamarin.forms

I am building a `Xamarin.Forms` project. I have now reached the stage where I need to use my own custom build of [Xamarin.Forms from github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) to fix bugs that affect my project.

Currently for my project I use `TFS` for my source control which works great.

Now of course I could download the `Xamarin.Forms` source and check it into `TFS` with my project and that would work great, but I would then not be able to submit bug fixes back to github or receive updates from github.

I would like to be able to have TFS and github working in tandem such that I can submit bugs/receive updates from github but also have the `Xamarin.Forms` custom build hooked up to `TFS` so that others in my team do not need to be set up with GitHub before they join the project.

Is this possible to set up so that the two work side by side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup your own Git repo for Forms and build (Nuget) packages from it.

Then in your project, add the local Nuget repo and references packages from there. This also allows you to easily switch between your own builds and the official Forms releases.

I use this setup with CocosSharp and am happy with it.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Do you have any resources on how to set this up? I don't know alot about Git or packaging Nuget packages.

Comment: That should help with the Nuget part: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx - I think Forms contains build scripts which will generate the Nuget packages for you.